# How to access a relative URI using StreamReader in C#

Tags: c#, file, relative-path, streamreader, streamwriter

So I'm trying to read/write to a generic .dat file which contains plain text. I've been trying to do it with StreamReader/Writer as this seemed to be the neatest way of doing things.

The data.dat file is in AllResources/saveData/data.dat inside my project and I'm struggling to access it using a relative file path (my code is in a different directory). Every method I've tried so far returns the following exception.

```
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path
```

Here is my code at the moment:

```
private readonly string _datFile = @"./AllResources/saveData/data.dat";
string data;
using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(_datFile))
{
    data = file.ReadLine();
}

if (data is null)
{
    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(_datFile))
    {
        file.Write(0);
    }
}
```

I haven't written to text-based files before using c# so if there are any better alternatives to StreamWriter suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this helps you to understand your current relative path.
step debug through that code:

```
// Create your base URI
var baseUri =  new Uri(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

// Create a relative URI
var relativeUri = new Uri( @"./AllResources/saveData/data.dat", UriKind.Relative);

// Combine them to get an absolute URI
var absoluteUri = new Uri(baseUri, relativeUri);

// Get the absolute path from the URI object
var absolutePath = absoluteUri.AbsolutePath;
```

Comment: The URI `./AllResources/saveData/data.dat`  contains an extra `net6.0-windows` directory before `AllResources` which might be causing the problem? I also noticed that the code your code returns the URI with \  instead of  / separating directories

Comment: if you store the data.dat and the resources directory in you project don't forget to set "copy to output directory" to copy it.

Comment: I've got that set to "copy if newer". I've tried both the "resource" and "content" build actions and neither work

Comment: you have a mismatch between the location of you file and the way you construct the pointer or path to it. Can you show both actual and expected paths?

Comment: I've found a botch fix which I'm going to stick to unless I have more time to fix this project at the end. I'm no longer specifying the path which saves the files to a random place in the Debug but gets the job done. Nevertheless, thanks for the help.